Running Oracle using Docker oci-oracle-free with Colima for Macbook M1
I am trying to run Oracle locally with Colima/Docker on a M1 ARM chip machine.
Following the instructions on this Github I did:

colima start --arch x86_64 --memory 4
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=tespass gvenzl/oracle-free
docker exec 24e6894e0c58 createAppUser test tespass

But in SQL Developer I have the error below. Any idea on what I can do?


Based on this answer I found the connection string should be:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/FREEPDB1


You can still use a 'Basic' connection in SQL Developer - change the settings in your image to have the 'Service name' option selected instead of 'SID', and enter FREEPDB1 as the service name value.
